# Why is my wife's Google Voice being forwarded to my Google Voice?

Tags: google-voice, email-forwarding

Recently, I've started getting Google Voice calls that are not mine.  The phone rings with my GV caller Id, I answer it and press 1 to speak to unknown caller, then I get a second prompt, this time telling me the caller's name, if I answer it, it is a call for my wife.

Somehow, I've got a daisy chain going here where my wife's GV is forwarding to my GV. I checked her settings and my GV is not listed as a forwarding number.

Could this somehow be related to our home phone VOIP being down due to internet being down?  That VOIP (voipo) is configured to use caller id of my GV, but I did not set it up to forward calls.

How can I untangle and debug the cause of this multiple forwarding?

My current forwarding rules are:

```
Google Chat: emailOne@university.edu
Google Chat: emailTwo@gmail.com
My Mobile telephone number (and receive text messages)
My Work telephone number
```

My wife's current forwarding rules are:

```
Google Chat: emailThree@gmail.com
My Wife's Mobile telephone number (and receive text messages)
Our home telephone number (VOIPO)
```

Comment: I think you should list all the forwarding rules/etc that you have. Also include any voicemail settings that you've allowed GV to handle instead of the default provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that VOIPO service was configured to forward calls when there was no answer to my Google Voice number.

Comment: Good find. Don't forget to "accept" this (when the timer runs out) so it acts as a signpost for future readers.